# Running performSelector: on an object that returns a double, not id

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, performselector

How can I run an arbitrary selector on an object, the return of which is a double?  For example, I have obj A, which has method -(double)blah;

How can I do `double res = [obj performSelector:@selector(blah)];`? performSelector returns an `id` type object, so should I cast from id to NSInteger to double - that will lose precision?

Also, I **do not** want to use the obj's `methodSignatureForSelector` (meaning, no `NSMethodSignature` and no `NSInvocation`) because it is a huge CPU drain at run-time.

Comment: Why `NSInteger`? Why not `NSNumber`?

Comment: Xcode compiler prevents casting to anything other than NSInteger.  Also, NSNumber is an object, but the method returns a double, not an object.

Comment: But you can init NSNumber with any primitive. Including double.

Comment: Ok, my mind just didn't want to think right, I see your problem now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uses least memory (valueForKey: uses two temporary objects) and the msgSend method doesn't work.

```
 IMP myImp1 = [obj methodForSelector:@selector(getDouble)];
 double aDouble1 = ((double (*) (id,SEL))myImp1)(obj,@selector(getDouble));
```

Comment: Maybe you would explain why you think this is a better solution?

Comment: No problem : ) In that specific case, I think using `objc_msgSend_fpret` is better, and actually more readable. You should always use function's casts with caution.

Comment: Definitely more readable.  Safety-wise, not sure what happens internally, but I can't imagine it does much more than expand to the IMP solution.

Comment: Actually, all the objc_msgSend* functions are implemented using assembly, so it might do a lot of things differently.

Comment: @Macmade I tried your method in favor of readability, but it doesn't work.  It only returns NAN, whereas the IMP method returns the valid results.   Take for example `    NSTimeInterval t = objc_msgSend_fpret([NSDate date], @selector(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate));`  Returns NAN.

Comment: Ok, see it now... Check the edit on my answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 8):

You may want to take a look at the Objective-C runtime functions, especially `objc_msgSend_fpret`.

```
double objc_msgSend_fpret( id self, SEL op, ... )
```

Which sends a message with a floating-point return value to an instance of a class.

The `performSelector` methods use `objc_msgSend`, which returns an `id` type.

For instance:

```
double res = objc_msgSend_fpret( obj, @selector( blah ) );
```

You'll need to import this objc runtime header:

```
#import <objc/message.h>
```

**EDIT**

By the way, here's the link to the ObjC runtime reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

**EDIT 2 - IMPORTANT**

`objc_msgSend_fpret` is implemented in different ways, depending on the CPU architecture (basically, i386 or x86_64).

As I said in a comment, those functions are implemented using assembly, so their implementations depends on the CPU architecture.

Under the x86_64 architecture, this function returns a `long double`.

This is why it fails (and returning NAN) when you assign it to a `double`.

Also note that there is an objc_msgSend_fp2ret function.

So, basically, my previous example will not work:

```
double x = objc_msgSend_fpret( obj, @selector( blah ) );
printf( "Val: %f\n", x );
```

As you noticed, it will print 'NAN'.

To make it work, you'll have to do it this way:

```
long double x = objc_msgSend_fpret( obj, @selector( blah ) );
printf( "Val: %Lf\n", x );
```

Here's a working example:

http://www.eosgarden.com/uploads/misc/fp.m

Compile it using:

```
gcc -Wall -framework Foundation -o fp fp.m
```

Comment: `objc_msgSend` and friends are declared in `objc/message.h`.  On Mac OS X, you can just import `objc/objc-runtime.h`, but on iOS you must import `objc/message.h`.  I edited the answer.

Comment: @Macmade Weird thing, but although it should work, it returns NAN, where the IMP method returns the valid result.  Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Macmade Chuck would win, but I don't like that it creates an NSNumber object, just to be cast to doubleValue. Plus, msgSend still doesn't work... `    long double x = objc_msgSend_fpret( [NSDate date], @selector( timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate ) );` x = NAN.

Comment: There's no prefect way. It all depends on what you want. Often, when dealing with such problems, performance may lead to a different approach (which can also lead to problems). It's also different if you actually wrote your `blah` method, or if it comes from a library/framework. Hope you'll find the right way : )

Answer (score 7):

If it's a method with no arguments, you can use `valueForKey:` and `doubleValue` on the value returned from that method. Otherwise, I think you'll have to muck with `objc_msgSend_fpret` to make it work.

Comment: The value that's returned from that method **is** a double, so using 'doubleValue' on it or 'valueForKey:' doesn't make sense.

Comment: @David: valueForKey: boxes primitives, so yes, what I said does make sense.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I like your solution.  It'd be the best, except it creates a temp NSNumber object.